# Ng-Repeat showing wrong values on Heroku

Tags: python, django, angularjs, heroku

I've developed a Django app that hosts some data and a login, and once logged in, the user interacts with an Angular app inside Django. On my local machine, everything works fine. And on the Heroku-hosted app, everything works fine except one weird thing. There is a particular ng-repeat that is mixing up values. Everything that should be shown on "index" is displayed on "index-1". This doesn't happen on my local hosted app, and it happens on the Heroku side in every browser I've tried. Here is the relevant code in my controller file:

```
sc.getMembers = function() {
    //get the list of members
    sc.editMemberPanel = [];
    sc.notTheOwner = [];
    sc.kickOutConfirmPanel = [];
    var members = mf.query({'id': sc.$storage.id},function(data){
        sc.$storage.members = [];
        for(i=0;i<members.length;i++){
            sc.$storage.members.push({
                name: members[i].fields.name,
                role: members[i].fields.role,
                phone: members[i].fields.phone,
                email: members[i].fields.email,
                status: members[i].fields.status,
                pk: members[i].pk
            });
            sc.editMemberPanel[i] = false;
            sc.kickOutConfirmPanel[i] = false;
            //if you own the band, you shouldnt be able to change your own status or email (or kick yourself out!).
            if(sc.$storage.yourUsername != members[i].fields.userName){
                sc.notTheOwner[i] = true;
            } else {
                sc.notTheOwner[i] = false;
            }
        }

    });
}
sc.getMembers();
```

Please note I've also injected $scope as 'sc'. Here is the relevant code in the view file:

```
<div class="panel panel-info" data-ng-repeat="(index, member) in $storage.members | orderBy: 'status'">
    <div class="panel-header" style="padding:10px;">
        <strong>{{member.name}}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div data-ng-hide="editMemberPanel[index]">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>Role</td>
                    <td>{{member.role}}</td>
                </tr>
            ...
            <button data-ng-show="$storage.isManager && notTheOwner[index]" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-ng-click="kickOutConfirm(index, true)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Kick out member</button>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="editMemberForm" data-ng-show="editMemberPanel[index]">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="E.g. Margaret Thrasher" data-ng-model="editMember.name" required /><br />
                </div>
            </div>
...
```

There are two buttons (Kick out member, and Edit Member). They are only displayed in a certain case. Now, the weird part, is that when you click them, they perform the functions on the correct index, so I know that the "index" variable is correct. But the buttons are displayed under the wrong member. Each one is on the "index - 1"th member. But, they are displayed in the correct position, so it's as if Angular is taking existing buttons and pushing them around somehow. All of the div's are balanced. I omitted several lines of code (including the Edit Member button). Why is Heroku mixing up the buttons? Oh, it's worth noting that in the base html file, I included Angular JS from the source. 
(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was iterating through items before displaying them and adding "show or hide" variables. The items were then displayed in a different order on the page. The iteration was going by date inserted, and the display on page was going by alphabetical. By explicitly declaring an index on each item in the iteration, and by displaying them in index order, I was able to solve this odd problem. I hope this helps someone else.